# Should all underlying elements be disabled when a jQuery dialog is showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page with a dialog I'm showing with `jQuery.dialog` (jQuery 1.7.1, jQuery-UI 1.8.18). I create it like this:

```
$(theDialog).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "800px",
    modal: true, // etc....
});
```

On the same page, I have a list control I've constructed out of a stack of `<div>` elements. I listen to clicks on the stacked `<div>` elements thusly:

```
$("#listEmployees div").on("click", "input", listEmployees_ItemClicked);
```

where `listEmployes_ItemChecked` is my event handler. When I show the jQuery dialog, most of the elements on the HTML page are disabled; i.e. they are unresponsive to mouse clicks &c. However, my stack of lists is not: if I click on the items in it, the event handler gets called.

To work around this issue, I had to introduce a global variable on the page, `isDialogVisible` which my dialog sets when it opens and clears when it closes. The event handler then ignores the event if the global variable is true. Needless to say, this is a hack and won't scale well.

My expectation was that the jQuery `dialog`, being modal, would disable all HTML elements and events from these elements while it is open. Is this expectation incorrect? Why am I still seeing mouse clicks when the modal dialog is up?

Comment: this is usually a z-index issue. The dialog creates an overlay above the page that prevents the user from interacting with it. If you're able to interact with a list on the page, it's z-index must be higher than the overlay/dialog. Take a look there.

Comment: Semantically, if it's a *modal* window, no other control on the page should respond while it is open. So yes, you should expect that nothing is accessible. 
But it could be your modal window has a z-index lower than the list you're still able to click...

Comment: So I can't expect jQuery's dialog() function to arrange for the dialog box to have a z-index higher than all other elements? Seems like that would be desired default behavior for a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI dialogs (earlier versions than 1.10) have a `zIndex` property. Set the `zIndex` to a value higher than any `z-index` being used within your CSS.

eg.

```
$(theDialog).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: "800px",
    modal: true,
    zIndex: 99
});
```

This feature was removed as of [jQuery UI v1.10](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-zindex-option):

> **Removed zIndex option**
>
> Similar to the stack option, the zIndex option is unnecessary with a
>   proper stacking implementation. The z-index is defined in CSS and
>   stacking is now controlled by ensuring the focused dialog is the last
>   "stacking" element in its parent.

jQuery UI dialogs do have the method `moveToTop()`, but this only moves the dialog to the top of the dialog context, so it is above any other dialogs on the page. It's the developers job to ensure their CSS doesn't cause stacking issues. 'Unfortunately', jQuery UI doesn't hold our hand all the time.